# Difference between int and unsigned int in C

Tags: c

I know that the range of unsigned int is 0<= I <= 2^32-1

However, when I type like this in C(visual 2015)

```
void main(){
   unsigned int k = -10;
   printf("%d",k);
}
```

then why computer print -10 on screen?? I think there should be error.

Comment: Try using `%u` specifier.

Answer (score 1):

`int` stores signed numbers by default, which means they can go from -2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,647 in range.  An `unsigned int` means you won't be using negative numbers, so the range is much larger because you have freed up the left most bit in your number which is normally used to indicate that it is signed (negative) or not.  So an `unsigned int` can go from 0 to 4,294,967,295.  This applies to types like `char` as well, they normally go from -128 to 127, when `unsigned`, a `char` holds one byte exactly, or 0 to 255.

Visual Studio (and most compilers) should give you a warning for trying to store a signed value into an unsigned type.

When you used `printf("%d",k)` The `%d` is telling `printf()` to print out a signed `int`.  So that is what it did.  If you want `printf()` to print out an `unsigned int` than you needed to use `printf("%u")`.

Answer (score 0):

in hexadecimal form, -10 is 0xFFFFFFF6

`unsigned int k = -10;` means

`unsigned int k = 0xFFFFFFF6;`

and when printing this value if you say

`printf("%d",k);` the compiler will evaluate the value (`0xFFFFFFF6`) as integer because of the `%d` specifier. (check http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/ about the issue)

if you say `printf("%u",k);` the compiler will evaluate the value (`0xFFFFFFF6`) as unsigned integer and will print a value between `0-2^32-1`